# getting easy_install to install something for python2.5 when default is python2.7

Tags: beautifulsoup, easy-install

since i'm using google app engine, i have to use python2.5.

because of this, i need to install an older version of BeautifulSoup that works with python2.5 (i think bs 3.0.7a will work).

in order to do that, as far as i can tell, i need to get easy_install to put BeautifulSoup in the python2.5 folder rather than in the python2.7 folder, which is does by default.

the docu for easy_install said the following:

"Also, if you’re working with Python version 2.4 or higher, you can run Python with -m easy_install to run that particular Python version’s easy_install command."

but how exactly do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this guide helped me get it right:

http://achinghead.com/installing-multiple-versions-python.html